# Eclipse RCP - Custom Rename participant

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, renaming, automated-refactoring

I created a custom [RenamePartipant](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/index.html?org/eclipse/ltk/core/refactoring/participants/RenameParticipant.html) as follows:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants">
  <renameParticipant class="com.project.explorer.RenameParticipantAction"
        id="com.project.explorer.renameParticipant1"
        name="Rename">
     <enablement>
        <with variable="affectedNatures">
           <iterate operator="or">
              <equals  value="data.nature">
              </equals>
           </iterate>
        </with>
        <with variable="element">
           <instanceof  value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
           </instanceof>
        </with>
     </enablement>
  </renameParticipant>
</extension>
```

, Custom Rename Participant createChange method as follows:

```
@Override
public Change createChange(IProgressMonitor pm) throws CoreException, OperationCanceledException {

    pm.beginTask("Rename task ", 1);
    CompositeChange change = new CompositeChange("Renaming " + changedResource.getName());

        if (isDataFile(changedResource.getName())) {
            return new DataResourceChange(changedResource.getFullPath(), getArguments().getNewName());
        }
    }

    pm.done();
    return change;
}
```

and a custom Change object as follows:

```
public class DataResourceChange extends ResourceChange {

private IPath resourcePath;
private String resourceNewName;
private long stampToRestore;

public DataResourceChange(IPath resourcePath, String resourceNewName) {
    this(resourcePath, resourceNewName, IResource.NULL_STAMP);
}

protected DataResourceChange(IPath resourcePath, String newName, long 
stampToRestore) {
    this.resourcePath = resourcePath;
    this.resourceNewName = newName;
    this.stampToRestore = stampToRestore;
}

@Override
protected IResource getModifiedResource() {
    return 
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().findMember(resourcePath);
}

@Override
public Change perform(IProgressMonitor pm) throws CoreException {
    pm.beginTask("Rename resource", 1);

    // IResource resource= getModifiedResource();
}

}
```

Whenever I rename a file, [RenameResourceChange.perform()](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fltk%2Fcore%2Frefactoring%2Fresource%2FRenameResourceChange.html) is called first which modifies the resource.

After that whenever I call getModifiedResource() method in my custom change class, it gives me null (as the resource has been moved).

How can I skip the default RenameResourceChange.createChange() method?

Comment: You can't skip the other participants, your participant should not expect that the original resource still exists.

Comment: Since other participants can update the resources, so how can I implement my own custom change to support Undo/Redo operations?